# My old Qt project file(.pro file), which was working; doesn't create any files (moc_ or .obj files). Why does it exit the build step doing nothing?

Tags: c++, qt, build, makefile, qt-creator

I have an old project (.pro) file. Suddenly, I am seeing that my project file doesn't create any files (moc_ or .obj files). It comes out of the build step doing nothing.

the compile output reads,

```
Starting: "c:\installations\qt\4.7.4\desktop\qt\4.7.4\msvc2005\bin\qmake.exe" D:\iCon\Misc\POC\DOE\DOELib\DOELib.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2005 "CONFIG+=release"
The process "c:\installations\qt\4.7.4\desktop\qt\4.7.4\msvc2005\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
Starting: "C:\Installations\Qt\4.7.4\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 

jom 1.0.3 - empower your cores

The process "C:\Installations\Qt\4.7.4\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
```

Comment: Should you be passing some options and switches to the jom compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running qmake to regenerate the makefiles?  I've sometimes found that if my .pro file has an earlier date than the Makefiles (possibly because I moved a file between computers with a different clock setting) that makefiles get stale and don't regenerate moc_* and ui_*.

Comment: I did regenerate make files. And as you are right I have to change the time zone of my system recently. surprisingly, it generated the files once but no luck after that.